# Как оптимизировать запрос UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE id IN (подзапрос)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Задача такова: нужно проставить полю **available** значение **TRUE** всем записям таблицы **product**, для которых найдется хотя бы одна запись **available** со значением **TRUE** в таблице **offer**. Поле **o.product_id** является внешним ключом (связь таблиц "один ко многим"). Можно как-то оптимизировать запрос?

```
UPDATE product SET available = TRUE WHERE id IN 
( SELECT DISTINCT( o.product_id )
    FROM product p
LEFT JOIN offer o 
    ON o.product_id = p.id
WHERE o.available = TRUE );
```

Comment: Какая СУБД? Не забывайте пожалуйста писать название СУБД и версию в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если оптимизировать абстрактный SQL, то для начала, внутри `IN` вам не нужен JOIN, достаточно `SELECT .. FROM offer o WHERE o.available = TRUE`.

Дальше нужно уточнять вопрос - почему потребовалось оптимизировать: сколько сейчас выполняется запрос, какие части тормозят (приведите план), какая физ. структура таблиц, размеры, кол-во обновляемых строк.